# kivy image and PIL image

Tags: image, class, camera, kivy

I can read an image using kivy camera. I wish to interpret a QR code in that image using code similar to this

```
texture = self.cameraObject.texture
size=texture.size
frame=texture.pixels
pil_image = Image.frombytes(mode='RGBA', size=size,data=frame)
pix=numpy.array(pil_image)
im=Image.fromarray(pix)

qrCodeDetector =cv2.QRCodeDetector()
decodedText, points, _ = qrCodeDetector.detectAndDecode(pix)
```

Kivy camera allows me to scan an image but to use the QR detector the image has to be converted to a numpy array

I have an import and then a class that starts off

```
   from kivy.uix.image import Image
   class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = None

     # and so on
```

The program runs but methods that are in the PIL Image class are not available. For example Image.frombytes and Image.fromarray which is needed to convert an image to another.

Changing the Image import to
`from PIL import Image`
The program crashes with error message

> ```
> class KivyCamera(Image):
> ```
>
> TypeError: module.**init**() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

How do I either do the image conversion using the kivy Image which seems impossible or how do I get the init module to accept the PIL Image class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import both `Image` classes like this:

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from PIL import Image as Pimage
```

Then, wherever you want to use the PIL Image, use `Pimage`:

```
pil_image = Pimage.frombytes(mode='RGBA', size=size,data=frame)
```